# Android: app Singleton and separate process service

Tags: android, service, nullpointerexception, singleton

I am testing a service in a separate process in my app. I am experiencing null pointer error when accessing some fields of the app singleton.
I think the singleton is not the same so I am asking here how to share the same singleton between the app and the service on separate process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separate process?  You don't.  That's the point of a separate process-  they don't share memory at all.  You need to communicate via IPC.